# How do I create a bootable backup disk image for my BeagleBone

Tags: disk-image, micro-sd-card, beaglebone

How do I create a bootable backup disk image for my BeagleBone? Current install is a on a 8GB micro SD card, the card I'm trying to copy it to is a 16GB card. I've tried using Win32DiskImager. But when I write the image back onto another the other card it doesn't boot.

the image I started with was the lastest Debian image from the beaglebone website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the 16GB microSD cards I was using were not bootable. I Ordered the same model except in 8GB and it worked.